# Bitcoin Core 0.13 -- jsonrpc interface -- conflicted transactions

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-core, transaction-malleability

I use bitcoind's `Wallet` feature to manage my bitcoins.
Using json-rpc interface, how can I check that a transaction is a conflicted one? And, how can I get `txhash` of a transaction, that spends those same outputs and is confirmed(malleability situation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `listtransaction`, you should get a JSON array called `walletconflicts`.

If your transaction conflicts with another transaction in your mempool or with a transaction in a block, this `walletconflicts` array is filled with `n` transactions-id's that points to the tx that spends the same, conflicting inputs.

`walletconflicts` is also present in `gettransaction`